# Read lines random number of times

Tags: c#

I need your help, i have a txt file with the following information that is loaded automatically :

```
     U 00024791
     0212-204T2HT
     Caracas, 12 de Julio       de 2016
     SAVAKE CA
     Estimado SCARLET
     D        1089274             101548895              444.825,68 BS
     D        6555555             101548895              444.825,68 BS
     D        9563221             101548895              444.825,68 BS
 FIN SCARLET SANCHEZ
```

I need to print in the console only the lines that start with D

Im try to use if statment or for but i dont really get it

```
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"p:\CARTAP1.txt");
        string input = readText[5];
        string result = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];

        foreach (string s in readText)
        {
            if (result == "D")
            {
                var cont = 0; 
                //string cont = readText[1];
                Console.WriteLine(cont);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Note: The lines that start with D are not always three, it varies which means it could be more than 10 lines that start with D and in that case i would have to print all of them on the console.

Comment: I suspect that is a tab between the D and the number field... if so then it should be input.Split('\t')  not input.Split(new char[]{ ' '}...

Comment: you have what your answer as part of your `NOTE` example there is something called `startswith` look up that function.. also if you are not familiar with that then use the `SubString function` what seems to be the problem..? have you even debugged the code to see what `s` contains..? also look at splitting on the proper token / delimiter also look at using the `continue` key word in your loop as well .. this is actually quite simple..

Comment: Thanks, i will check! It has been debugged and s contains all the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"p:\CARTAP1.txt");
foreach (string s in readText)
{
    if (s.Trim().StartsWith("D"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

And with Linq:

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"p:\CARTAP1.txt");
foreach (string s in readText.Select(s => s.Trim()).Where(s => s.StartsWith("D")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping the newbie out with some easy to read and easy to understand code.

Comment: Yep, i am a newbie! Thanks Kevin

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"p:\CARTAP1.txt").Where(w => Regex.IsMatch(w, @"^\s*D"));
```

[You can play with the Regex here](https://regex101.com/r/rP4vV6/1)